# Android onClick add array value to ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple app with facts and fact numbers.

```
String facts[] = {"Elephants are the only mammals that can't jump.",
            "Candles will burn longer and drip less if they are placed in the freezer a few hours before using.",
            "Potatoes have more chromosomes than humans.",
            "Butterflies can taste with their hind feet.",
};

String factNumber[] = {
                "Fact 1 of 5000",
                "Fact 2 of 5000",
                "Fact 3 of 5000",
                "Fact 4 of 5000",
};
```

I have a favourite button, and when the button is clicked, I want the Fact and Fact Number to get added to a ListView, so I can view my favourites whenever I want.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Why don't you use an ArrayList for the facts ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class like this:

```
class Fact {
    String fact;
    String factNumber;
    boolean favorite;

    //...
}
```

Use a `List` or an array of these objects to display your data. In your adapter you can check a `favorite` variable to decide what icon to show.

In an `OnClickListener`, change this boolean flag to the opposite value. And update the UI.